# How to use drawRect with a subclass of UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement an owner-drawn view that is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  Basically, I want to custom-draw the contents of the view, and then have the stuff I've drawn be scrollable.

I've overridden `drawRect` in my view and I'm able to draw my contents, scaled to the size of the UIScrollView's contentSize property (so some of my custom drawing is not visible, as I intended).

The problem is that the content then never moves.  I can drag my finger up and down, and this makes the UIScrollView's scrollbars appear, but my custom-drawn content never moves or changes - I still always only see the top half.

How can I custom-draw content for this UIScrollView so that what I've drawn is scrollable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you calling `[super drawRect];` at the end of your own `drawRect` method?

#### Edit

I misread the question. You'll need to create your own `UIView` subclass and put your overridden `drawRect` in that. Then, add that view as a child of the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I figured I would have to do that, but it's odd that there appears to be no way to do custom drawing onto the scrollable content part of a UIScrollView.

Comment: I don't think there is a 'scrollable part' of a UIScrollView. It simply scrolls all of it's child views.